# Как правильно работать с БД

Tags: база-данных, node.js, веб-программирование, mongodb, веб-сервер

В своем web-приложении я использую Node.js + Express + MongoDB. Допустим я должен выполнить запрос к БД и вывести ответ пользователю с помощью http, используя fetch на клиенте. Я делаю это таким образом:

```js
server.post('/get_post/:heading', async(req, res) => {
    const getPost = () =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const collection = req.app.locals.posts;
            const projection = {
                _id: 0,
                heading: 1,
                content: 1
            };
            const { heading } = req.params;

            collection.findOne({ heading }, { projection }, (err, result) => {
                if(err) reject(new Error(err));
                else resolve(result);
            });
        });

    var post;

    try {
        post = await getPost();

        if(post === undefined)
            return res.sendStatus(404);
    } catch(err) {
        return res.sendStatus(502);
    }

    res.json(post);
});
```

Этот код работает без проблем, но думаю что я возможно не проверил какой-то случай или оставил уязвимость для хакера. Хочу понять, является ли этот код безопасным для продакшена?

Comment: Почему функция называется getUser, почему post_id это поле name?? ниже отпишу немного отформатированный код, но в принципе уязвимостей как таковых нет, кроме проверки авторизации юзера, если таковая есть, ибо инпутится только post_id

Comment: Ок, исправил недочеты. Спасибо за комментарий

Comment: Я проблем с безопасностью не вижу. Других также.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше не доставать коллекцию откуда-то из `req...`, а доставать из модуля через `require`, еще - лучше использовать mongoose, ибо там можно сразу модели реализовать и не нужно оборачивать колбэки в промисы

Отформатированный код:

```
const error = (res, error = 'Internal server error', statusCode = 500) = {
      return res.status(statusCode).json({error, statusCode})
}

const findOneAsync = (collection, searchParams, projection ) => 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            collection.findOne(searchParams, { projection }, (err, result) => {
                if(err) reject(new Error(err));
                else resolve(result);
            });
    })

server.post('/get_post/:heading', async(req, res) => {
    const { heading } = req.params;
    if (!heading) return error(res, 'Invalid req param heading', 400);

    try{
        const post = await findOneAsync(
            req.app.locals.posts, 
            { heading }, 
            { _id: 0, heading: 1, content: 1}
        );

        if (!post){
            return error(res, `Post with heading: ${heading} not found`, 404)
        }

        res.status(200).json(post);
    } catch (err){
        return error(res, err)
    }
})
```

Comment: Чем этот код принципиально отличается от ТС?

Comment: @TotalPusher разве  что читаемостью, также отсутсвие var, убраны лишние куски кода, ошибки отдаются с месседжами.

Comment: @TotalPusher также не считаю нормальным кейсом делать проверку (post === undefined)

Comment: @Shiki Почему не стоит доставать коллекции через req.app.locals?

Comment: @TotalPusher не совсем понятно, как туда попадает коллекция, не явный путь, если ты покажешь этот код другому человеку, он не сразу поймет откуда она  там берется и что там вообще берется. Чтобы посмотреть на саму коллекцию, сначала придется искать, где она объявляется, вместо явного require(), где ты через ctrl можешь кликнуть и перейти в файл.

Comment: @Tucha, сообщение сверху, случайно не тебя линканул, в основном придирки по код стайлу, уязвимостей нет.
Вообще, в будущем лучше используй либо монгуз, либо реализуй класс для коллекций, где функции уже будут промисами, чтобы на каждом роуте не создавать новую функцию, которая возвращает new Promise

Comment: @Shiki Спасибо!